# t.test between two groups one with 4 observations and another with 2

Tags: r

> Error in t.test.default(x[1:4], x[5:6], na.action = "na.pass") :    not enough 'y' observations

Is the error message I get when trying the following:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) { t.test(x[1:4], x[5:6], na.action="na.pass")$p.value}))
```

Is there a way I can run a T.test using only x2 observations in one group?

Comment: You need to make the question reproducible by providing example data.

Comment: although not ideal, you should be able to run a two-sample `t.test` with a sample size of 2 in one of the groups. Depending on software, the calculation of the sample variance uses the [Bessel's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) to correct for bias introduced when estimating the population variance (`n-1` instead of `n` in the denominator). In this case, the sample variance cannot be calculated if one of the groups only has sample size 1. Check if any rows have `NA`'s in them which causes `x[5:6]` to only have 1 data point available.

Comment: I agree with @avid_userR. I would guess that your data have some `NA` values that are causing some of the "groups" to have only 1 value, which would generate the type of error you are seeing.

Comment: Dear avid_useR and jdobres 

Thanks so much for the help. Before running the t.test, I cleaned my df by running na.omit. 

I hope you are having a good week

Answer (score 0):

The answer go out to avid_user.
The problem that your data contains `NA`. Please see the code below as demonstration. Hence you should use `na.omit`, or to use some imputation package like `MICE`:

Code without `NA`:

```
t.test(1:5, 1:2)
```

gives an output:

```
    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  1:5 and 1:2
t = 1.7321, df = 4.5, p-value = 0.1503
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.8026856  3.8026856
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
      3.0       1.5
```

Code with `NA`:

`t.test(1:5, 1:NA)`

throws error:

> Error in t.test.default(1:5, c(NA, 1)) : not enough 'y' observations